# Should service methods use each other or should I use one, then use the next one independently?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a REST API where users, depending on their permissions, are allowed to interact with certain items. I have the basic methods for get, post, delete, and update, but I also have methods to check if a user can access an item or update/delete it.

In this context, most of the time I won't be able to just get an item from the database, first I need to look for the user sending the request, find its permisses on the item, and then retrieve it (or delete or whatever).

So my question is: should my basic methods call the permission check methods by themselves or should I, for example, 1st call a check method from the API controller, 2nd throw an exception if something in the check fails (permissions, notFound...),3rd call the basic method if everything is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with REST paradigm you should return code [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) for users with no privileges to access that method. Ideally, all user privileges/permissions are encoded in web token, so it is part of user query context (you know that user has privilege to call the method before calling it). Same goes with all other reply codes - use your best judgement applying the correct response code (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).